# ES2015 compilation failing when setting NODE_PATH

Tags: node.js, gulp, babeljs

I'm trying to get a node.js application up and running where I can:

- use the latest features in ES2015
- have a simpler import path (https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520#better-local-require-paths-for-nodejs)

I've got the first part all figured out, but for some reason when I update the NODE_PATH environment variable, everything goes to crap. I've been trying to debug this for about a day and can't seem to find the right solution.

If someone can help point me in the right direction, I would totally appreciate it. Thanks!

Github repo: https://github.com/alvincrespo/failing-es2015-compilation

#### terminal output

```
➜  app git:(master) ✗ npm start

> app@1.0.0 start /path/to/app
> NODE_PATH=./src gulp

[15:20:29] Requiring external module babel-register
[15:20:29] Using gulpfile ~/workspace/app/gulpfile.babel.js
[15:20:29] Starting 'default'...
[15:20:29] Starting 'server'...
[15:20:29] Finished 'server' after 496 μs
[15:20:29] Starting 'build'...
[15:20:29] Starting 'clean'...
[15:20:29] Finished 'clean' after 5 ms
[15:20:29] Starting 'babel'...
[15:20:29] Finished 'babel' after 269 ms
[15:20:29] Starting 'copy'...
[15:20:29] Finished 'copy' after 1.67 ms
[15:20:29] Finished 'build' after 277 ms
[15:20:29] Starting 'restart'...
[15:20:29] Finished 'restart' after 8.94 ms
[15:20:29] Starting 'watch'...
livereload[tiny-lr] listening on 35729 ...
/path/to/app/src/routes.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import usersController from 'controllers/users';
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/app/dist/index.js:19:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I didn't quite understand how NODE_PATH could be set to allow for "absolute" resolved paths. The update I had to make was to set the NODE_PATH to the dist directory:

#### package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_PATH=./dist gulp",
    "test": "NODE_PATH=./dist gulp test"
  },
```